# bluetooth button is gone

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

As you can see, the button that turns on the bluetooth is gone.I can no longer use my mouse and I can not use Bluetooth at all. Please help me. What can I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODh0.png)

Comment: Open Device Manager and look for Bluetooth under Bluetooth and Networking.  Is it there and OK or Red mark saying Not there. I had the Bluetooth Daughter card go on my X230 and IBM replaced the card.

Comment: I only see Bluetooth when I click show hidden devices.

Comment: Can you select it and see properties?  I do not need to check Hidden on either Laptop here to see Bluetooth.  Is it in the Network section?  It must be there too.

Comment: Action Center provide a screenshot of it.

Comment: you can try below steps. Bring up the start menu> Search for "Device Manager".>Go to "View" and click "Show hidden devices">In Device Manager, expand Bluetooth>Right click on Bluetooth Generic Adapter and update the driver or you can disable it and reanable it> Restart PC. More methods you can try https://techcult.com/wiki/fix-option-to-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-is-missing-from-windows-10/

Comment: Unless you can see properties as we have suggested, it would appear the Bluetooth card has failed.